# unable to find suitable angular data grid for angular 2.4.1 version?

Tags: angular

Added  these two lines to the dependencies list in `package.json` like to get data grid template

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "ag-grid": "3.3.x",
    "ag-grid-ng2": "3.3.x"
    ...
  },
}
```

The above two lines adds the dependencies related to ag-grid after that  run   npm install to download.
Then  added the code into the component for data grid

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {AgGridNg2} from 'ag-grid-ng2/main';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-datatable',
    directives: [AgGridNg2],
    template: `
         <ag-grid-ng2 #agGrid style="height:100%;width:845px" class="ag-fresh"
            [gridOptions]="gridOptions">
         </ag-grid-ng2 >
     `
})

export class AppComponent { 
    myRowData = [
        {"name":"Ronald Bowman","country":"China","city":"Lutou","email":"rbowman0@spotify.com"},
        {"name":"Pamela Hill","country":"Russia","city":"Krylovskaya","email":"phill1@symantec.com"},
        {"name":"Robin Andrews","country":"Ukraine","city":"Korop","email":"randrews2@photobucket.com"},
        {"name":"Peter Kim","country":"Mexico","city":"San Jose","email":"pkim3@theatlantic.com"},
        {"name":"Carol Foster","country":"Mexico","city":"El Aguacate","email":"cfoster8@intel.com"},
        {"name":"Jimmy Burke","country":"Indonesia","city":"Banjarsari","email":"jburke9@over-blog.com"},
        {"name":"Jonathan Crawford","country":"Peru","city":"Alca","email":"jcrawforda@deliciousdays.com"},
        {"name":"Donald Montgomery","country":"Poland","city":"Działoszyce","email":"dmontgomeryb@google.com.br"},
        {"name":"Donna Shaw","country":"Japan","city":"Akune","email":"dshawc@chronoengine.com"},
        {"name":"Helen King","country":"United States","city":"Hollywood","email":"hkingd@devhub.com"},
        {"name":"Walter Myers","country":"China","city":"a ndaowa n", "email":"wmyerse@state.tx.us"},
        {"name":" Alice Collins","country":"Papua Nw  Guine a", "city":"Mendi","email":"acollinsf@npr.org"},
        {"name":"Anne Richards","country":"China","city":"Koramlik","email":"arichardsu@vinaora.com"},
        {"name":"Randy Miller","country":"Indonesia","city":"Trenggulunan","email":"rmillerv@oakley.com"},
        {"name":"Phillip Adams","country":"Bahamas","city":"Duncan Town","email":"padamsw@lycos.com"},
        {"name":"Nicholas Allen","country":"Philippines","city":"Bautista","email":"nallenx@aboutads.info"},
        {"name":"Lisa Willis","country":"Thailand","city":"Lat Yao","email":"lwillisy@istockphoto.com"},
        {"name":"Jeffrey Castillo","country":"Indonesia","city":"Karangsari","email":"jcastilloz@washington.edu"},
        {"name":"Michael Carpenter","country":"Colombia","city":"Cali","email":"mcarpenter13@prlog.org"},
        {"name":"Roger Lee","country":"France","city":"Courtaboeuf","email":"rlee14@earthlink.net"},
        {"name":"Steve Wallace","country":"Russia","city":"Novobeysugskaya","email":"swallace15@cisco.com"},
        {"name":"Shirley Patterson","country":"Peru","city":"La Tinguiña","email":"spatterson16@woothemes.com"},
        {"name":"Nancy Ward","country":"Sweden","city":"Båstad","email":"nward17@mapquest.com"}
    ];

    columnDefs = [
        {headerName: 'Name', field: "name", width: 200 },
        {headerName: 'Country', field: "country" ,width:180},
        {headerName: 'City', field: "city" ,width:160},
        {headerName: 'e-mail', field: "email" ,width:300}
    ];

    gridOptions = [];

    constructor() {
        this.gridOptions = {
            rowData: this.myRowData,
            columnDefs: this.columnDefs,
            enableColResize: true,
            enableSorting: true,
            enableFilter: true
        }   
    }
}
```

Getting error `"cannot find module angular2/core"` But I found that its not version compatible.. Is there any data grid compatible with angular 2.4.1 version.

Comment: Have you tried https://material.angular.io/components/component/grid-list or https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/datatable

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using primeng datatable ?

Well documented and great features like filter,crud , templating.

https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/datatable

Comment: do we need to add it in dependencies and whether its compatible with angular 2.4.1 version

Comment: npm install primeng --save  . https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/setup  this is the installation and yes it will be compatible with angular 2.4.1  . primeng would be the best since they started on early development aswell      Note: installation should add the dependency automatically

Answer (score 0):

For others who may find this helpful...

Clarity is a third party open source component library for angular created by VMware. The data grid is full featured. I have added it to the asp.net core 2.2 spa template pretty easily by following the getting started instructions on the clarity project site. You may need to upgrade your cli and angular version to use the newest clarity version but I found it worth it.

https://clarity.design/documentation/datagrid/structure

https://clarity.design/